# GAM method without resampling in caret produces stop error

Tags: r, r-caret, training-data, gam

I wrote a function within lapply to fit a GAM (with splines) for each element in a vector of response variables within a data frame. I opted to use `caret` to fit the models instead of directly using `mgcv` or the `gam` package because I would like to eventually split my data into a train/test set for validation and use various resampling techniques. For now, I simply have the `trainControl` method set to 'none' like so:

```
  # Set resampling method
  # tc <- trainControl(method = "boot", number = 100)
  # tc <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 1)
  tc <- trainControl(method = "none")

  fm <- lapply(group, function(x) {
  printFormula <- paste(x, "~", inf.factors)
  inputFormula <- as.formula(printFormula)
  # Partition input data for model training and testing
  # dpart <- createDataPartition(mdata[,x], times = 1, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
  # train <- mdata[ data.partition, ]
  # test <- mdata[ -data.partition, ]
  
  cat("Fitting:", printFormula, "\n")
  # gam(inputFormula, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mdata)
  train(inputFormula, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mdata, method = "gam",
        trControl = tc)
})
```

When I execute this code, I receive the following error:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  Only one model should be specified in tuneGrid with no resampling
```

If I re-run the code in debugging mode, I can find where `caret` stops the training process:

```
if (trControl$method == "none" && nrow(tuneGrid) != 1) 
    stop("Only one model should be specified in tuneGrid with no resampling")
```

Clearly the `train` function fails because of the second condition, but when I look up the [tuning parameters for a GAM](https://topepo.github.io/caret/Generalized_Additive_Model.html) (with splines) there is only an option for feature selection (not interested, I want to keep all the predictors in the model) and the method. Consequently, I do not include a `tuneGrid` data frame when I call `train`. Is this the reason why the model is failing in this way? What parameter would I provide and what would the tuneGrid look like?

I should add that the model is trained successfully when I use bootstrapping or k-fold CV, however these resampling methods take much longer to calculate and I do not need to use them yet.

Any help on this issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that model, the tuning grid looks over two values of the `select` parameters:

```
> getModelInfo("gam", regex = FALSE)[[1]]$grid
function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
   if(search == "grid") {
      out <- expand.grid(select = c(TRUE, FALSE), method = "GCV.Cp")
   } else {
      out <- data.frame(select = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = len, replace = TRUE),
                         method = sample(c("GCV.Cp", "ML"), size = len, replace = TRUE))
   }
    out[!duplicated(out),]
 }
```

You should use something like `tuneGrid = data.frame(select = FALSE, method = "GCV.Cp")` to only evaluate a single model (as error message says).

Comment: I was able to successfully fit the GAM models using the tuning parameters you suggested. I understand that feature selection is disabled and looking up the GCV.Cp I see that it is passed to the `gam` function in the `mgcv` package. In the future, what source can users consult on options for the tuning parameters? On the GitHub website, I think the documentation could at least link the user to the potential options for the tuning parameters. That's just my two cents. Thank you for your help, I'm sure I'll have more in the future!